# How to count how many different word do i have in a file, in a column

Tags: text-processing

I have a CSV file.

```
"AGNOLI Valerio","ITA","AST"
```

In this example, the 2nd column says "ITA". I expect there are about 100 or so different nationalities listed in this file. I want to know exactly how many different nationalities there are.

Answer (score 4):

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 filename | sort -u | wc -l
```

Basically, I am specifying the `,` as the delimiter in the `cut` command and extracting the values in the second column using `-f` flag. Now, I sort them using `sort` and the `-u` flag makes the command to list only unique values. Finally, I have the `wc -l` command to get the count of unique countries in the second column.

**Testing**

```
cat filename
jill,us,123
jack,us,345
jill,en,234
mark,en,432
kate,us,354
kane,ru,435
```

Now, after issuing the command, I get the output as,

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 filename | sort -u | wc -l
3
```

Comment: maybe add `| wc -l` at the end? I think the OP wanted to count different nationalities.

Comment: @Simply_Me, thanks. I added the `wc -l` to the end.

Comment: `sort | uniq` may be shorten to `sort -u` (also more efficient). See also `LC_ALL=C sort -u` to report unique lines, as opposed to lines that sort the same (won't make a difference if that's only ASCII letters though).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks. I have made the changes as you suggested. :)

Comment: Note: this will fail if there are `,` in any of the quoted fields.

Comment: you don't need `cut`, `sort` can sort columns: `sort -u -t, -k2`

Comment: Quoting CSV fields is optional, so long as the field does not contain a delimiter character.  This solution will fail if the second column contains a mix of quoted and unquoted data (some nationalities will be reported twice).

Comment: There's no need to quote the comma, since it is a regular character. The following is valid and still does what OP wants: `cut -d, -f2 filename | ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` which will do it more efficiently and do the count for you instead of invoking different binaries and forking a lot of processes.

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]++} END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' filename.csv
```

Comment: Note: this will fail if there are `,` in any of the quoted fields.

Comment: @richard based on `"AGNOLI Valerio","ITA","AST"` I'm not sure how it will fail.

Comment: I assume that the 2 examples are just example, else we could tell you the answer is 1. Can I also assume that there are no commas in the fields of other records.